# What does the turtle eat?

Tags: strange-world

In *Strange World*, there is a type of large turtle-like organism:

> that actually seems to be thousands of miles across and hosts the entire landmass that the people of Avalonia live upon.

The "turtle" is shown to have a digestive system, so it does not solely rely on photosynthesis or some other autotrophic form of digestion. We also see that at least one non-turtle form of plant life exists on the planet, the parasitic plant pando, so there seem to be other organisms that it could theoretically eat.

So what does the "turtle" eat? Or is it turtles all the way down?

Comment: Space kelp, I'm guessing